# Many Many to Relationship

Tags: custom-object

I have a requirement of creating a many to many relationship between two objects Owner and contractor. My idea is to firstly create the juntion object and establish Master Detail Relationships on the junction object.

Later If I load the data(owner and contractor) through dataloader will the many to many realationship be in effect immediately or do i have to check for each and every record?

Comment: You can use External Id during import process

Comment: @RasMisha Hey, I am new to salesforce. What do you mean by external id?

Comment: Create for Owner and Contractor fields Owner_External_Id__c and Contractor_External_Id__c (and mark as external id). And map ids from csv on this fields. And when you upload junction data (through upsert in dataloader) you can use this external id fields for mapping. Sorry for my english.

Comment: may be this link can help you http://focusonforce.com/integration-and-data-loading/using-dataloader-for-lookups/